# Broken Icons/font in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

I'm trying to configure Windows Terminal to use this fancy icons & theme for Windows Terminal
I followed Scott Hanselman youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lu__oGZVT98

But looks like that I did something wrong with the font! It's broken as you can see below small squares instead of showing the icon or font character.

[image]

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that [Scott Hanselman updated his post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToMakeAPrettyPromptInWindowsTerminalWithPowerlineNerdFontsCascadiaCodeWSLAndOhmyposh.aspx).
I found the solution at the end of it

And I just updated the fontFace as he said, and it works :D

```json
"fontFace":  "Cascadia Code PL"
```